# Model REST service

Tags: rest, model, restful-architecture, api-design

Say I have a merchant "account"... We have the typical `/api/v1/merchantaccount` `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Each merchant can have multiple users. These are the merchant's users, like: admins, clerks, staff, NOT shoppers of the merchant.

Do I create the merchant user endpoint under: `/api/v1/merchantaccount/user` and offer `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`

Or do I implement a complete separate service: `/api/v1/merchantuser`

Also when I authenticate the merchant user should I create separate endpoint or keep the same?

`/api/v1/merchantaccount/user/authenticate`

vs

`/api/v1/merchantuser/autneticate`

Comment: Both paths are okay. The authentication must not create a server side session.

Comment: Maybe i should clear it up a bit. The paths are to demonstrate wether I should physically separate as 2 service/api or just 1. I sometimes feel that REST gets to fine grained for nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two distinct notions at play here:

1. The endpoint's (resource's) name: if that's the only user-related resource/endpoint that your API is going to have, then naming it `User` should be fine.
2. The path through which it can be accessed: if the use case scenario only requires the users to go to the website/api and login, then there's no reason for them to have to go through the `MerchantAccount` entity (the link between a merchant and a user is probably set during registration)

Comment: Im using the uri to demonstrate wether i should treat as 2 separate physical api/apps/services.

Comment: looking at the [Richardson Maturity Model level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1), I'd say yes, the `merchant` (account) and its `users` are two distinct entities

Comment: Also to make that link between merchant and user why go through 2 separate apis. When you can do it in 1 shot?

Comment: by "make that link" you mean retrieve merchants and also users? if you were to embed the merchant's users in the same call, imagine when you do a query on all the merchants...do you really want to pull that much data from the DB in a single call, when you probably need just a small fraction? ideally you'll have links from merchants to users (see level 3 in the previous link), but again, it all depends on your use case scenarios: how are your clients going to consume this? without this info it's not easy to get tailored answers

Comment: Well, it comes downto how we would collect the info. Like the rest of the world its 99% a input form which is usualy backed by a web app. So... A human registers to create a merchant account. A few options here. 1 create a merchant account. Then ask to create 1 user. Or the other way. Create user and then ask to create merchant account. Or ask for both pieces of information and do it 1 shot. The first 2 throw transactionality out the door or really complicate it because the back end has to coordinate with 2 REST apis. The 3rd option is done one shot 1 api 1 call to db.

Comment: I guess in the first two options if step 1 fails ask to try again. If atep 1 passes and step 2 fails. Worst vase you jave a danling account or you can ask the iser to rertry step 2 again.